# PHP script within jQuery generated content

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this code to generate bubbles which are then populated with text from a mySQL database: http://jsfiddle.net/exr4N/1/. I added my query here to retrieve the text:

```
    <div id="parent">
       <?php 
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10");

          $i = 1;

           while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

             $comments = new Comment($row);

          echo  ('<div class="message">'. $comments->markup() .'</div>'); 

           $i++;

          }?></div>
```

I am not happy with the bubble animation so I would like to use this script instead: http://codepen.io/PastaMIya/pen/tEcLF. However, I cannot figure out where to add my PHP code.  I tried adding it like this:

```
      // Create the bubbles
       for (var i = 0; i < bubbleCount; i++) 
         {
      $bubbles.append('<div class="bubble-container"><div class="bubble">
        <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10");

           $i = 1;

             while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
          $comments = new Comment($row);

          echo  ($comments->markup()); 

               $i++;  }?>

           </div></div>');

          }
```

and then in the HTML like this:

```
         <?php 
          // Output the bubbles one by one:
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10");

       $i = 1;

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {

          $comments = new Comment($row);

          echo  ('<div class="bubbles">'. $comments->markup() .'</div>'); 

      $i++;
              }
      ?>
```

but neither worked.  If anyone can give me a bit of direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. I am new to this and am still trying to make sense of it all.

Thanks in advance.

*** EDIT ***
I guess maybe it boils down to is there something else I can use instead of append() to output the bubbles? For example, is there a way I can move the function that generates the bubbles in the second script into the HTML page and generate the bubbles in the same way my current script does?

Can I move this:

```
 $bubbles.append('<div class="bubble-container"><div class="bubble">
```

into the HTML page like this script does:

```
  var message = 1;
     $('.message').each(function (message) {
     $(this).verticalMarquee(1, 1, message);
     message++;
   });
```

or is there something I can use instead of append()?

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the output of the rendered php?

Comment: For the first one within the append(): http://jsfiddle.net/R7n9s/

The one I am currently using (working properly): http://jsfiddle.net/a735n/

Comment: The generated HTML with the rendered PHP is in the top HTML section of the Fiddle in both since I couldn't paste it into the Results section of course.